# Meteor external js file load order in smart package

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm working on a smart package for meteor that requires an external api. I need to load the api, and then load a file that makes use of that api after the api has been loaded.

What is the proper way to define a load order like this in a smart package?

Answer (score 2):

If you've added your smart package into your meteor project the package will be loaded before your meteor code runs.

If you mean in your API you're going to be loading stuff and the loading order matters there, the order that you use `api.add_files` in would be used. (See example : https://github.com/avital/meteor-xml2js-npm-demo/blob/master/packages/xml2js/package.js)

So if you want to do something after all the other files have loaded I guess you could just put the code for that in file and add it as the last `api.add_files`.

For code in around the meteor directories and folders, the load order is (as from the meteor docs):

- Files in the lib directory at the root of your application are loaded first.
- Files that match main.* are loaded after everything else.
- Files in subdirectories are loaded before files in parent directories, so that files in the deepest subdirectory are loaded first (after lib), and files in the root directory are loaded last (other than main.*).
- Within a directory, files are loaded in alphabetical order by filename.

Comment: In this instance, I need to load a file that is external (google maps api), and after that file has loaded I need to load a file that depends on it. What would be the correct way to do that?